# PHP regex recursivo

Tags: php, regex

Eu tenho que validar a sintaxe de expressões como essas:

```
(ind(10)+15)-10
1000-(perg(25)*2)
25/var(1)
12*2-(58+1)/5
```

ind, perg e var são funções.

Estou tentando resolver dessa maneira:

```
$var = '(\((var[\(])[0-9]+\)\)|(var[\(])[0-9]+\))';
$perg = '(\((perg[\(])[0-9]+\)\)|(perg[\(])[0-9]+\))';
$ind = '(\((ind[\(])[0-9]+\)\)|(ind[\(])[0-9]+\))';
$number = '[0-9]+(\.|,){0,1}[0-9]{0,2}';
$ope = '(\+|\-|\*|\/)';


$x = '('.$ind.'|'.$var.'|'.$perg.'|'.$number.')';
$a = $ope;
$s = '/^('.$x.$a.'(?R)|\('.$x.$a.'(?R)\)|(?R)'.$a.$x.'|\((?R)'.$a.$x.'\)|'.$x.')$/';

print_r(preg_match($s, '(perg(6)*perg(4)*)*1000000'));
```

E está gerando esse erro:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: recursive call could loop indefinitely at offset 359
```

Vou tentar explicar como tentei resolver esse problema

```
Pensei na segunite expressão regular: 'X A S' or 'S A X'

X-> são os valores;    
A-> um operador matemático;    
S-> um expressão.    

A-> + ou - ou * ou /;    
X-> ind(número) ou perg(número) ou ind(número) ou número float;    
S-> X A S ou (X A S) ou S A X ou (S A X) ou X
```

Comment: O que você deseja não pode ser produzido por REGEX, pelo fato de ser mais complexo, ja que se trata de um analisador Lexico. Só o fato de você ter de fazer balanceamento de `()` já o torna complexo para ser feito via regex. Você tera de desenvolver um analisador Léxico.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme pela ajuda. Você poderia me indicar algum material para que eu possa conseguir resolver esse problema? Se possível em PHP.

Comment: [Writing a simple lexer in PHP](http://nitschinger.at/Writing-a-simple-lexer-in-PHP/), Este material é muito bom para dar um base, pode pesquisar por "PHP parser" ou "PHP Lexer", são dois termos envolvidos.

Comment: Muito obrigado Guilherme, vou estudar sobre o assunto.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Esse é um conselho muito bom. No entanto, os lexers também podem usar regex. Para uma validação tão simples, eu não acho que não pode ser produzido por regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos simplificar:

```php
$oper   = '[-+*\/]';           //um operador matemático
$numero = '(?:- ?)?\d*\.?\d+'; //float
$nomes  = '(?:var|perg|ind)';  //nomes de função

$recurse= '(?1)'; //Vou explicar depois
```

Como os parênteses permitem qualquer expressão matemática dentro, podemos definir:

```php
$parens = '\(' . $recurse . '\)';    //=>  \((?1)\)
```

E as funções também têm a mesma sintaxe, portanto, podemos colocar os nomes das funções como opcionais antes de um conjunto de parênteses (pense em parênteses como uma função sem nome):

```php
$funcao = "$nomes?$parens";          //=>  (?:var|perg|ind)?\((?1)\)
```

Então, temos os **valores**:

```php
$x = "(?:$numero|$funcao)";          //=>  (?:(?:- ?)?\d*\.?\d+|(?:var|perg|ind)?\((?1)\))
```

Que pode ser seguido qualquer número de vezes por um operador matemático com outro valor:

```php
$s = $x . "(?:$oper$recurse)*";      //=> (?:(?:- ?)?\d*\.?\d+|(?:var|perg|ind)?\((?1)\))(?:[-+*\/](?1))*
```

E colocamos tudo entre parênteses para que seja este mesmo o que recursa:

```php
$regex = "/^($s)$/";
```

#### Expressão regular

```php
/^((?:(?:- ?)?\d*\.?\d+|(?:var|perg|ind)?\((?1)\))(?:[-+*\/](?1))*)$/
```

<kbd>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JhAkrX/1)</kbd>

#### Por que `(?1)`

`(?R)` casa recursivamente ao padrão inteiro, mas isso nunca pode coincidir com `^` no meio do texto. Em vez disso, `(?1)` permite de forma recursiva **coincidir com o grupo 1** (que neste caso engloba a expressão inteira excepto as âncoras). Veja *[Recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.recursive.php)*.

Graficamente:

[image: Setas marcam de onde e para onde a chamada recursiva é feita]

---

#### Código

```php
function validar($expr) {
    $oper   = '[-+*\/]';           //um operador matemático
    $numero = '(?:- ?)?\d*\.?\d+'; //float
    $nomes  = '(?:var|perg|ind)';  //nomes de função

    $recurse= '(?1)';

    $parens = '\(' . $recurse . '\)';
    $funcao = "$nomes?$parens";

    $x = "(?:$numero|$funcao)";
    $s = $x . "(?:$oper$recurse)*";

    $regex = "/^($s)$/";
         //=> /^((?:(?:- ?)?\d*\.?\d+|(?:var|perg|ind)?\((?1)\))(?:[-+*\/](?1))*)$/

    return preg_match( $regex, $expr);
}


//  EXEMPLOS
$exemplos = [
        '9-8+',
        '(ind(10)+15)-10',
        '(ind(10)+15-10',
        '1000-(perg(25)*2)',
        '1000-perg(25)*2)',
        '1000-perg(25)*2',
        '25/var(1)',
        '12*2-(58+1)/5',
        '(perg(6)*perg(4)*)*1000000',
        '0'
    ];

foreach ($exemplos as $expressao) {
    echo (validar($expressao) ? '✔️' : '✖️') . " $expressao\n";
}
```

#### Resultado

```
✖️ 9-8+
✔️ (ind(10)+15)-10
✖️ (ind(10)+15-10
✔️ 1000-(perg(25)*2)
✖️ 1000-perg(25)*2)
✔️ 1000-perg(25)*2
✔️ 25/var(1)
✔️ 12*2-(58+1)/5
✖️ (perg(6)*perg(4)*)*1000000
✔️ 0
```

Veja funcionando no http://ideone.com/nHl0Mo